# Search for Three Consecutive Lines of Text Inside a File

Tags: windows, powershell

**Problem:** I need to search for some text inside a file, it contains three *consecutive* lines of text. How do I verify (find the existence of) those lines are in the file?

**Expected Return Value**: A boolean

---

**Example Input File**: *text.txt*

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

**Example Pattern to Search For**

```
two
three
four
```

Comment: You should check out [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for tips on asking questions so you can get quality, tailored responses. Responders expect [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to be followed. For some pointers, consider [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6) and [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6).

Comment: Are the three lines consecutively written in the file? Are there line feeds and carriage returns between lines? What do you expect the code to output if you find the lines in the file and what do you want it to output when you don't find the lines? Do you need to know the line numbers of the matched text? Does case-sensitivity matter? How large is the text file? Is this code expected to iterate through many text files? We could provide general answers but they may not be what you need. Code examples would be helpful.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Yes they are consecutive with new line/carriage return, and I just need to know the existence of these lines.

Comment: Use a -SimpleMatch parameter on Select-String, or just use -match on a Get-Content variable to find the pattern, then if ($found) {do something} to notify you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple Answer**:

```
$file = (Get-Content -Raw file.txt) -replace "`r" # removing "`r" if present

$pattern = 'two
three
four' -replace "`r"

$file | Select-String $pattern -Quiet -SimpleMatch
```

RE-EDIT.  Wow.  This is a tricky way to do it.  At the prompt, $pattern has no "`r", but in a script it does.  This should work as a script or at the prompt.

```
$file = (get-content -raw file.txt) -replace "`r"

$pattern = 'two
three
four' -replace "`r"

# just showing what they really are
$file -replace "`r",'\r' -replace "`n",'\n'
$pattern -replace "`r",'\r' -replace "`n",'\n'

# 4 ways to do it
$file -match $pattern
$file | select-string $pattern -quiet -simplematch
$file -like "*$pattern*"
$file.contains($pattern)

# output
one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\n
two\nthree\nfour
True
True
True
True
```

Hmm, trying a regex way.  In single line mode, a . can match a "`r" or a "`n".

```
$file = get-content -raw file.txt
$pattern = '(?s)two.{1,2}three.{1,2}four'
# $pattern = 'two\r?\nthree\r?\nfour'
# $pattern = 'two\r\nthree\r\nfour'
# $pattern = 'two\nthree\nfour'
$file -match $pattern
$file | select-string $pattern -quiet
```

Comment: These all evaluate to false when I run them (all 6 test cases).

Comment: How did you make $file and $pattern?  It has to be the same way I did.

Comment: I just copied over your script into a ps1 file and ran it.

Comment: That worked, thank you. The escaped newline and carriage return makes sense.